# push a View Controller after an amount of time

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app that ends with a View Controller saying "Thanks for using the blabla app, have a nice day."

I am trying to find a way so that after 20 seconds the app refers itself to the first View Controller, allowing a new user to input there data.

Do you guys have a clue?

Comment: [NSTImer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/)

Comment: 20 seconds is a really long time to have the user wait on a screen. Just add a button there.

Comment: Yes, suggestion of @EmilioPelaez is perfect. 20 second is long time I think too. Please reduce it to 5 sec or add an UIButton.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use NSTimer in your `viewDidLoad` to archive this:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(20, target: self, selector: "dismissVC", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

then call its method:

```
func dismissVC() {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
}
```

Or you can use `sleep` to delay 20s in your `viewDidLoad`, like so:

```
sleep(20)
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set timer for 20  second and after 20 Pop  method will call and in pop method you can pop to root view controller.

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(20, target: self, selector: #selector(YourClass.Pop), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func Pop() {
 self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All objects have this function

```
public func performSelector(aSelector: Selector, withObject anArgument: AnyObject?, afterDelay delay: NSTimeInterval)
```